# How to reduce the width and increase the height of triangle created by css

Tags: html, css

I am creating a triangle with pointing towards bottom using html and css. Here I need to reduce the top width and increase the height of down pointer little bit, I tried with lots of modification, it does not work.

```css
.triangle-with-shadow {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   
}
.triangle-with-shadow:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: #999;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   bottom: 75px;
   left: 25px;
   box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.triangle-with-shadow:hover, .triangle-with-shadow:hover:after {
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-with-shadow"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS everything is treated as rectangle ([BOX-MODEL](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)). It’s annoying, but makes sense, If you try to apply `box-shadow` on rectangle layout, it's back-breaking task. So Instated of using `box-shadow` you can use Filter `drop-shadow`. Filters are not bound to the box model. That means the outline of our triangle is recognized and the transparency around it is ignored so that the intended shape receives the shadow.

Try this code:

```css
.triangle-with-shadow {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;

}
.triangle-with-shadow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px 20px 0 20px;
  border-color: #999 transparent transparent transparent;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  filter: drop-shadow(-1px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}

.triangle-with-shadow:hover,
.triangle-with-shadow:hover:after {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-with-shadow"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here one problem is coming that box shadow is not coming surrounding the triangle,its coming surrounding the square box if I add the box shadow into .triangle-with-shadow:after{box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}